# Non-Parametric Entropy Pooling View and Constraint Matrix Structure

Tags: entropy-pooling

Meucci has a compelling system to merge a prior distribution with subjective views about risk drivers called Entropy Pooling. The original paper is [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1213325). In the non-parametric (scenario-based) approach, we take a $J \times N$ matrix $X$, where $J$ is the number of simulations, and $N$ is the number of assets. Then we associate a $J \times 1$ vector of probabilities $p$ to each simulation outcome. From there we create a $J \times K$ matrix of views $V$, where $J$ again represents the number of scenarios, and $K$ represents a generic function of the market. I can't quite visualize what the $J \times K$ matrix would look like for standard views. Let's say that I have simulated 10 joint scenarios for a two-variable standard normal distribution.

$$      \mathbf X=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -.85 & 1.02 \\
        1.62 & .36 \\
        .31 & .93 \\
        -.53 & .36 \\
        1.1 & -.84 \\
        -1.49 & .30 \\
        1.45 & -.31 \\
        .37 & -.64 \\
        .96 & -.29 \\
        1.01 & .97 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
        \space
        \space
        \mathbf 
        p=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        .1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I have two views: asset one will have an average of $.5$, and asset one will have a standard deviation of $.1$. How do I transform these standard views into a conformable $J \times K$ matrix?